# Can you load template from string in Meteor's Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Can you load a template from string in Meteor's Iron Router instead of doing `this.render('pageName');`?

In other words can you have:

```
var html = "<div>{{todo}}</div>";
this.render(html);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the package [numtel:template-from-string](https://github.com/numtel/meteor-template-from-string/) which makes Blaze templates with the Spacebars from string.